# Simplexml count inside a do-while loop

Tags: php

I am trying to do a simplexml count inside a do-while loop, yes its simple but the count is not correct as it is inside 2 loops.  Is there a easier way to do the count?

```
$query_fl = "SELECT * FROM table";
$fl = mysql_query($query_fl, $rf) or die(mysql_error());
$row_fl = mysql_fetch_assoc($fl);

do {
    $xml = $row_fl['fu'];
    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmlDoc->load($xml);

    $rss = simplexml_load_file($xml);
    $items = $rss->channel->item;

    foreach($items as $item){
        echo $rss->channel->title;
        echo $feed_count."<BR>";
        $feed_count++;
    }

    $feed_count=1;

} while ($row_fl = mysql_fetch_assoc($fl));
```

------------- **The output is like this**

```
Feed 1 - Count-1
Feed 1 - Count-2
Feed 1 - Count-3
Feed 1 - Count-4
Feed 1 - Count-5

Feed 2 - Count- 1
Feed 2 - Count- 2
Feed 2 - Count- 3
...
..
```

---------------**I want the output as**

```
   Feed 1 - Count-5
   Feed 2 - Count-3
```

Comment: Can you specify `first_feed` element in your loaded xml? Because it is not mentioned anywhere in your above code snippet. If you provide such more details then solution can be more visible.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using mysqli instead of mysql_* as that is now depricated, but moving on... You have a couple of options, either:

1) move $feed_count=1; to before the do loop for a single count of all items.

or

2) make an array of counts for the foreach loop, incrementing the array index each time you exit the foreach loop. This will give you an array of counts for your items. If you use a key derived from an item variable e.g. its name, then you can count the number of occurences of an item type, even if they are not all together in your xml.

Comment: Perhaps you should say what you would like to see - what you have added looks like what I would expect to see.

Comment: @a1 check the end of the question the output I require is there. Just updated the Q

Comment: Then my option 2 above would work, you increment the array each cycle of the foreach loop, you use the feed number as the key. When all the loops have finished you look at the array.

Comment: If there is a feed count of 5 in the first_feed that is going to be excuted 5 times.  Then the array() will not work correctly.